# Need AMP price range slider

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I'm developing a mobile site with AMP project. My project require a price range slider based data searching like the airbnb have, to see the airbnb Price Range slider, please [Click here](https://github.com/airbnb/rheostat)
[image]

I didn't find any Price range slider on AMP yet which will fulfill my need.

Could you please check the [link](https://github.com/airbnb/rheostat) i have attached and let me know your concern including how can i implement a price range slider on my project with AMP as like airbnb have.

Comment: Are you bound to use any technology ? If not then why not clone the git repo in link

Comment: @rach8garg I think it's because they made it using react. He needs AMP version.

Comment: @ChrisAbyAntony you are right. I need AMP range slider. Here I added react slider for example.

Comment: @engr.jalal Do you need the exact same implementation? If you are okay with having two sliders you could implement using `<input type="range" />`. Give it a try and share your result. I will try something as well.

Comment: @ChrisAbyAntony Yes, I need the exact same design implementation.

Comment: What did you try by far and what challenge are you facing?